# Get window of certain tab in Applescript

Tags: applescript

So I'm trying to set the variable called `theWindow` to a window with a tab whose URL contains `"google.com"`.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set theTabs to a reference to (tabs of windows whose URL contains "google.com")
    set theTab to item 1 of theTabs
    set theWindow to window of theTab
end tell
```

However, this doesn't work and the code returns:

```
Google Chrome got an error: Can’t get window of tab id 384 of window id 383." number -1728 from window of tab id 384 of window id 383
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Chrome so you may have to convert but this is how it might be done with Safari.

```
    tell application "Safari"
        set sst to "google.com"
        
        repeat with w in windows
            if exists (tabs of w whose URL contains sst) then
                set wix to index of w
                set wid to id of w
                set theWindow to window id wid
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell

    try
        display dialog "Window: " & wix & return & "Window ID: " & wid
    end try
```

It cycles through open windows and checks if any of its tabs have a matching URL. If at least one does, then it provides the index and ID for that window. Obviously, if multiple tabs match the search term then the result will be affected.

Comment: Works perfectly, I had to modify the script a bit so it does what I actually asked for.

Comment: Glad to hear that. It's actually kind of a vexing issue. Feel free to append my answer with the Chrome code for any future readers.

Comment: I can't edit it because the suggested edit queue is apparently full. But the things I changed were: `set sst to "nikon"` should be `set sst to `google.com` and before the `exit repeat` I added `set theWindow to window wid`

Comment: You want me to edit the answer to include those changes?